# VMWARE Server 2 on Windows 7 and Invalid Code-Page Error

Tags: vmware-server, windows-7

I've just installed VMWARE Server (2.02) on a clean install of Windows 7 64bit Pro (***systems code-page was set to Big5***) and then tried to import some existing VM's from a previous install (Windows XP, VMWARE Server 2.01, CP=codepage-1252).

The web ui reported an error- invalid vmx file.

After searching on google a possible fix came up which is changing the .codepage to Big5 in the VMX file (it was .codepage=codepage-1252) - however I was still unable to import the VM's.

So, to try and fix the problem I changed the windows systems code-page to codepage-1252... 
But now the vmware web ui wont start - reporting an invalid code-page MS-950.

I've tried un-installing and re-installing vmware server several times all to no avail!

Anyone have any clues as to where I can look to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer was *relatively* simple in the end. The clue (to myself) was that I was coming from a background of an XP machine...

**1.** On Win7 (Vista too?), it looks like the machines locale can apply in different user accounts. I had modified my own account - but not applied the changes to "All" accounts - more specically - the systems account. So, whilst half the system was now codepage-1252 the vmware web service was under big5.

Not sure why, but it really does'nt like that.

Under Windows 7 there is an option (new for me) of applying your codepage to all users/accounts whilst XP used to only have a single "system locale".

Changing that fixed the web service problem nicely.

**2.** And now, for being unable to load the old VM's. That came down to a code page issue. Once I'd looked at the VMX file using the good old trusty "type" i could see double spaced characters.

Reverting to trusty Notepad++ (a most excellent program by the way), loaded the file up and changed the encoding to ANSI saved it down and then re-imported the VM.

Result... Success! Phew..

---

And now, I must say, looking back, why on earth did I cause myself so much grief and pain by *upgrading* (???) from XP to Windows 7? 
Is it really going to be worth the hassle for the extra 4GB of memory space??